# Multithreaded Spring Boot Application leaves MySQL processes in sleep state

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, multithreading, amazon-aurora

I have a Spring Boot Application for cron tasks. One of those tasks is executed as a group of several threads executed asynchronously. Each thread inserts ~200K data in MySQL compatible AWS Aurora Serverless DB. Before the task is finished, all the threads are being shutdown upon their completion, but the corresponding processes in MySQL remain in the process list with **'sleep'** status. Here is the shorten sample:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledServiceApp implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ScheduledServiceApp.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("scheduled-task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
     }
}


@Component
public class ScheduledTask {

    // .....

    @Scheduled(cron = "${task.cron.expression}", zone="UTC")
    // @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    public void runTask() {
        try {
            // .....

            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);

            for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; ++i) {
                Runnable task = new TaskThread();
                executor.execute(task);
            }

            executor.shutdown();

            while (!executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                // wait until the processes in the executor will be terminated
            }

            log.info("Task is completed successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log the error
        }
    }
}


public class TaskThread implements Runnable {
    // .....

    public void run() {
        dataService.insertData(/* parameters */);
    }
}
```

Each separate thread execution may last for ~30min because of the huge amount of data to be processed and after the task's completion, in MySQL console I still see the corresponding processes which are in 'sleep' mode and which are being terminated only after the timeout value reaches.

As you can see in the code, `@Modifying` annotation with its parameters didn't help either. Also, I don't want to decrease the timeout value since that may affect on queries running directly in MySQL as well. But I would like to terminate those processes since they affect on application's overall performance.

**So my questions is:** is there a solution which will make the MySQL processes to be terminated instead of being slept when my task is finished?

**Update:** Forgot to mention that the application is completely container managed and running under Tomcat. JDBC/ODBC bridge for MySQL (Aurora Serverless MySQL 5.7 compatible).

Comment: To be able to answer on how to get rid of the processes more information is required:
How many database connections stay open? What are you using to run the application (Tomcat? Others?). Which driver and what driver configuration do you use?
Also open connections in sleep state do not have a tremendous amount of overhead and do not influence performance of individual queries in a measurable fashion. The main risk you run is our of connections (e.g. hit the configured limit in which the DB will not allow new connections)

Comment: Each thread "connects" to the database, but it sounds like it is missing a matching "disconnect".

Comment: Can you try to use autoCommit parameter in the JDBC connection to true in your TaskThread  class perhaps ?

Comment: @RanjitM, it is autoCommit, because the data are being committed into DB but the processes still remain.

Comment: @Rick James, as it is a container managed application the connection are being created or pulled by the container and hence, it is though that the disconnection is also handled.

Comment: @Armine, might be using try-with-resources statements or by calling the close method on the Connection object .  try (Connection connection = dataService.getConnection()) in TaskThread class

Comment: @RanjitM, as I already mentioned, my appllication is completely managed by the container and I don't open/close connections manually, it's all done automatically by Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Spring Boot apps use HikariCP for connection pooling. So basically the HikariCP is in charge of DB connection lifecycle. So when one of your threads tries to execute any DB-related action, like read or write data to DB, it asks HikariCP to give it a connection, as the connection creation process is pretty slow and requires lots of resources, HikariCP by default keeps the connection in the pool for a configured time. So you will need to refer to the `maxLifetime` and `idleTimeout` properties from HikariCP [Documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

And as you are on spring boot, you may control the HikariCP from you `application.properties` file with the following config options.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=XXXX
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=XXX
```

Comment: Spring Boot uses Hikari by default but there are other connection pools supported as well. For the mentioned configurations to work, please verify the pool used. Then for that pool, find the configuration which sets the maximum amount of time a connection is allowed to stay idle. for eg. for hikari its spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout which defaults to 600000ms ( 10 minutes). Your connections would be released as soon as a connection remains idle for this much time.

Comment: Why do you want to have another status for connection ? The connections are open without activities.
The other solution is to only start your springboot for your batch and to stop it after

Comment: @PhilippeKernevez, I don't want to have another status for my connections. And my application is a cron job running on a daily basis or whatever. All I just want is not to have too many slept processes in MySQL, because my logic is that when the process did its work, it should be finished and not remained in the processes list slept 6 - 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

> all the threads are being shutdown upon their completion, but the corresponding processes in MySQL remain in the process list with 'sleep' status

Spring boot uses HikariCP as a Default DB Connection Pool. When the transactions are closed, Connections are not closed. Rather, DB connections are returned to the Connection Pool. So, MySQL must be showing those idle connections.

> So my questions is: is there a solution which will make the MySQL processes to be terminated instead of being slept when my task is finished?

If the connection pool is not used, then all the connections are opened when required and closed when transactions are completed. MySQL won't show those sleep processes then. Please try setting below to disable connection pooling -

```
spring.datasource.type=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource
```

But, if you disable DB Connection Pool, there are downsides to it -

1. MySQL will refuse connections when max connection limit on MySQL is exhausted.
2. You won't get those benefits of connection pooling like connection reuse and a cap on maximum open DB Connections by the application.

I suggest you find how many concurrent connections are needed by your application. Then fine tune HikariCP connection pool property `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size` so that connection pool is not impacting application performance.

Comment: I would avoid disabling connection pooling since it is prone to create other problems which the application haven't before.

Comment: yes @Armine, I am not suggesting to disable connection pool. I mentioned that setting only to check that those mysql processes are due to connection pools. I suggest to tune connection pool properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using these connection pool properties, and set the following in your application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=XXXXX
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=XX
```